# rspec --innit; in .bash_profile not working

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec, keyword

Why can't I access the instance variable?

```
let(:hotel2) { Hotel.new name: 'Premier Inn', rating: 1, 
                 city: 'Leeds', total_rooms: 15, features: [] }
```

I am calling it in the initialize but it keeps throwing an incorrect argument error.

```
def initialize()
    @name = name
    @rating = rating
    @city = city
    @total_rooms = total_rooms
    @features = features
  end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization signature does not match your calling signature.  You are passing a hash, but not receiving one. There are a number of ways to define argument lists to make this work.  Here is one:

```
class Hotel
  def initialize(hash)
    @name = hash[:name]
    @rating = hash[:rating]
    @city = hash[:city]
    @total_rooms = hash[:total_rooms]
    @features = hash[:features]
  end
end
```

[This blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) outlines how to use Ruby V2 keyword arguments.  That would be another, perhaps better, way to define your `initialization`.  Here is an example of that:

```
class Hotel
  def initialize(name: , rating:, city:, total_rooms:, features:)
    @name = name
    @rating = rating
    @city = city
    @total_rooms = total_rooms
    @features = features
  end
end
```

You can set defaults for keyword arguments and make them mandatory.  In this example, they are all mandatory.